# Shifting Characters in a String with Determined Increments

Tags: java, arrays, string, for-loop, char

The following method will shift the characters in the string correctly if the increment is set at 1. I am having difficulty when i set the value of 'k' any higher. What might be causing the issue?

```
String cyclicLeftShift(String s, int k){

        String finalString = "";

        char[] newString = s.toCharArray();
        char[] secString = new char[newString.length];

        for(int r=0; r<k;r++){
            secString[secString.length-1]=newString[0];

        for(int i=0; i<s.length()-1; i++){ 
            secString[i]= newString[i+1];
        }
            newString = secString;
    }

        for(int c=0; c<secString.length; c++){
            finalString+=secString[c];
        }
        return finalString;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that you're not clearing secString every time. You really want a separate, local variable for it. The following modified code works, although you'll probably want to change the variable names:

```
static String cyclicLeftShift(String s, int k) {

    String finalString = "";

    char[] newString = s.toCharArray();
    char[] globalSecString = new char[newString.length];

    for(int r=0; r<k; r++) {
        char[] secString = new char[newString.length];
        secString[secString.length-1]=newString[0];

        for(int i=0; i<s.length()-1; i++) { 
            secString[i]= newString[i+1];
        }
        newString = secString;
        globalSecString = secString;
    }

    for(int c=0; c<globalSecString.length; c++){
        finalString+=globalSecString[c];
    }
    return finalString;
```